# How to process events from Buttons inside Repeaters? And what's this EnableEventValidation thing?

Tags: asp.net

I have a `Repeater` with a `Button` inside the `ItemTemplate`. I added the `CommandName` property to the button and registered and event handler for the `ItemCommand` event on the `Repeater`.

My problem is that when I click the button, I get an `ArgumentException` with a message saying something about `EnableEventValidation` being set to `true`.

(By the way, is there a way I can get the message in English, instead of a lousy Portuguese translation?)

I tried setting it to `false` and the `ItemCommand` handler is not called. If I set it to `true` I get the error.

The message also says something about using `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation` if I trust the client (which I do). The problem is I can't make sense of the documentation for that method.

Comment: A lousy Portuguese translation?

Comment: I am Portuguese and I don't understand it. The problem is terms like postback are translated and that gets impossible to understand.

I can post it if you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lookout for the binding problem pointed out by Steve Robbins and you may also want to take a look at [this](http://aspalliance.com/1343_Handling_Events_within_a_Repeater_Control_Using_ASPNET_20.all) article which I found pretty useful when I was stuck in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks. That solves it. Though the code is in VB, but I managed.

Comment: VB is not my language of choice but I try to work around it. Glad I was of help.

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've ever seen this is when I was rebinding the repeater in the Page_Load on postback, rather than wrapping the binding in an if (!Page.IsPostBack).  If you do this then the control that's sending the message is effectively invalid, so it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Only Problem is Postback is Happening Before ItemCommand Event of Repeater Could happen....i.e why asp.net is throwing a Event Validation Error

If u r Binding Repeater inside Page Load Write it Inside If(!PostBack){...}