# Repeater with Buttons doesn't fire OnItemCommand even when DataBind doesn't happen when IsPostBack is true

Tags: asp.net

I've got an image button in a Repeater, which is in a User Control, and I can't get the OnItemCommand event to fire when I click it. It always gives the error: "... Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using ..."

When I change the image button to a link button, it doesn't give me the error, but it still doesn't fire the OnItemCommand function.

I found some other relevant answers (such as [How to process events from Buttons inside Repeaters? And what's this EnableEventValidation thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411491/how-to-process-events-from-buttons-inside-repeaters-and-whats-this-enableevent)) but they all say, "Make sure you're data-binding your repeater inside of a if(!Page.IsPostBack) block." I have done that, but it didn't make a difference.

Here's the markup for the repeater:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptExpenses" OnItemDataBound="rptExpenses_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="Button_Command" runat="server" >
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ibDelete" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

Here's some exerpts from the code-behind

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (!IsPostBack) {
        rptExpenses.DataSource = ExpenseIds;
        rptExpenses.DataBind();
     }
  }

  protected void rptExpenses_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
     if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) {
        var ibDelete = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("ibDelete");
        ibDelete.CommandArgument = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
     }
  }

  protected void Button_Command(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     var btn = (IButtonControl)sender;
     switch (btn.CommandName) {
        case "Delete":
           //delete it
           break;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why this was happening in the answer to this question: [Why ItemCommand doesn't fired on My Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546853/why-itemcommand-doesnt-fired-on-my-repeater?rq=1)

Turns out that for some reason the Page's DataBind function was invalidating the repeater's controls without passing through the repeater's OnItemDataBound function a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptExpenses" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibRemove" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" runat="server"
            CommandName="Remove"
            CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>'
            OnCommand="ibRemove_Click"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And this in the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        rptExpenses.DataSource = ExpenseIds;
        rptExpenses.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void ibRemove_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (IButtonControl)sender;
    switch (btn.CommandName)
    {
        case "Remove":
        //delete it, use btn.CommandArgument to find id to remove
        break;
    }
}
```

If you still receive the `... Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using ...` error, it most likely means that you are somewhere re-binding the repeater before the `ibRemove_Click(...)` event is raised.

Comment: I tried this, but it still gives me the same behavior. I put the "OnItemDataBound" function back in, and put a break point there (just to make sure that it wasn't called during the postback of the button) and it wasn't. Is it possible that the repeater is binding again without going through that function?